# Validate UK short (outward) postcode

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, postal-code

I'm using this validator:

```
//validate postcode
function IsPostcode($postcode)
{
    $postcode = strtoupper(str_replace(' ','',$postcode));
    if(preg_match("/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2,3}[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode) || preg_match("/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode) || preg_match("/^GIR0[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[From this link.](http://www.townscountiespostcodes.co.uk/postcodes/tools/php-postcode-validation-script.php)

But I want to be able to validate postcodes like ME20 and TN10 instead of a full blown ME20 4RN, TN0 4RN.  This is the part of the postcode known as the 'outward code'.

Can someone help me out with the regex?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: There is a library available to do this https://gist.github.com/ChrisMcKee/4452116 just set the incode optional to only validate the first part

Comment: How much do you understand about regex patterns? It would only take the most basic regex knowledge to work out your answer from the starting point you've already got. I suggest going and [reading up a bit more about regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) rather than asking such a basic question. You'll learn a lot more that way.

Comment: I know nothing about them really, but I did just buy "Mastering Regular Expressions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use my updated regex to solve you problem

it working from my end to validate UK zip code

```
<?php 
function IsPostcode($postcode)
{
    $postcode = strtoupper(str_replace(' ','',$postcode));
    if(preg_match("/(^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]?[\s]?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}$)/i",$postcode) || preg_match("/(^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]$)/i",$postcode))
    {    
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

echo $result = IsPostcode('ME20');
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

1

Hope this will sure help you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for some codes.   The very first one I checked it with, NW1 doesn't make a match.